# OfType<> Method Not Functioning in OData after upgrade to EF5 and .NET 4.5

Tags: inheritance, wcf-data-services, entity-framework-5

I recently upgraded an OData service from .NET 4.0 with Entity Framework 4 to .NET 4.5 and Entity Framework 5. My edmx map looks perfect, with all of the inheritance set up exactly as I had it before. I am using TPH inheritance and all of the mapping is still correct with the correct discriminators. Yet, I am unable to use the .OfType<>() operator with the OData service. I do not get an error that the OfType is not supported, but rather that the `resource could not be found`.

I am using verbose errors and that is the only response I get. I have a unit test that directly hits the DBContext that functions with the OfType operator fine. I had originally been working with the ObjectContext, but i changed to the DBContext to see if that would solve my issue.

I'm at a loss since I am not getting any errors. My map is fairly complex so I don't want to try and recreate the entire thing.

Comment: A few questions:
1) Where exactly are you using OfType? (IE, client vs server) 
2) What is the URL being requested?
3) Was the OfType working before the upgrade? 
4) Did anything else change when you made the switch to EF 5.0? For instance, did you start using DbContext?

Comment: 1) Client side OfType for OData. I have a Server Side OfType hitting the entities directly that works fine. When I do an OData OfType request, I get no resources.
2) http://localhost:31487/TestDirectorySearchService.svc/Tests/TestDirectoryModel.OrderableBase() is one of the urls
3) Yes
4) I made no other changes to the service. I was on ObjectContext, Made the upgrade to 4.5 and EF5. The OfType did not work. I switched to DBContext and the OfType still did not work.

Comment: Using OfType<MyNamespace.MyType>() on client should produce a URI like: http://host/Service.svc/TestEntities/MyNamespace.MyType. Are you seeing that happen? What is the exact URL that causes the 404?

Comment: @MattMeehan Yes. 

TestDirectoryModel.OrderableTest() is the end of the url. Exact is in my previous comment.

`http://localhost:31487/TestDirectorySearchService.svc/Tests/TestDirectoryModel.OrderableTest`

Comment: Sorry, the link was truncated in the earlier post and I didn't notice the real href had the full type name. Assuming that exact type name appears in that namespace in your edmx, I can't think of any reason why this would 404. Have you tried setting IncludeExceptionDetailsInFaults to true on your service? Its separate from UseVerboseErrors, and goes in a [ServiceBehavior] attribute on the DataService<T>. It should cause a stack trace to appear for most errors, which will help with diagnosing the issue.

Comment: Also, what version of WCF Data Services are you using?

Comment: @MattMeehan I do have the IncludeExceptionDetailsInFaults set. I was using Microsoft.Data.Services version 4 when I first ran into this problem. I've sinced updated my service to use 5.

My .svc file:
`<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Factory="System.Data.Services.DataServiceHostFactory, Microsoft.Data.Services, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
 Service="TestDirectorySearchService.TestDirectorySearch" CodeBehind="TestDirectorySearch.cs" %>`

That is the only thing I changed, so I may not have changed enough.

Comment: Did you change the assembly references in the project/web.config? Changing the .svc file is not enough, though I'm not sure why it would cause this error.

Comment: I had not upgraded my nuget to 5.2 for the WCF Data Services. I upgraded and still did not solve the problem. I am now remapping the edmx to see if there's something in there.

Comment: @MattMeehan I am going crazy. I have done a complete remap of my model (all manual because our db is old). I can get the OfType to function when directly hitting my entities. However, I still get no resources when using it with OData. I'm really saddened as I was really hoping to take advantage of the Entity Framework upgrades.

Comment: Can you provide the actual error message and stack trace using a web debugger like Fiddler? Like I said before, I have no idea why you're getting this error, and I'd really like to get to the bottom of this. You're welcome to send me a repro at 'mmeehan' at msft, if that's an option. For the URI being requested, your mappings could cause an empty feed to be returned, but you should not get a 404 because of the mappings. You should only get a 404 if that type does not exist, which is independent of your mapping, and depends purely on the CSDL section of the edmx.